# Regular expression for first 4 characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for 4 characters. The first 3 characters must be a number and the last 1 must be a letter or a digit.

I formed this one, but it not working

```
^([0-9]{3}+(([a-zA-Z]*)|([0-9]*)))?$
```

Some valid matches: `889A`, `777B`, `8883`

Comment: Alphabet or digit: [a-zA-Z0-9]. Or just [a-z0-9].

Comment: the first three character should be a number only and last character may be a alpabet or digit

Comment: There is a lot wrong here- you probably need to find an introduction to Regular Expressions and learn the basics first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/28hw3sce(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 13):

> `I need a regular expression for first 3 will be a number and the last 1 will be a alphabet or digit`

This regex should work:

```
^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

This assumes string is only 4 characters in length. If that is not the case remove end of line anchor `$` and use:

```
^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: @PCA: Wondering if this worked out for you?

Answer (score 9):

Try this

This will match it anywhere.

```
\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This will match only beginning of a string

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

You can also try this website: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It makes it very easy to create and test your regex.

Comment: `{1}` makes no sense, remove it. Note that `\w` also matches an underscore `_`. Use `[^\W_]` instead

Comment: I know it's monday but don't forget the letters :P

Comment: Works fine and + for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the stars out...

```
^([0-9]{3}+(([a-zA-Z])|([0-9])))?$
```

The stars mean zero or more of something before it. You are already using an or (`|`) so you want to match exactly one of the class, or one of the other, not zero or more of the class, or zero or more of the other.

Of course, it can be simplified further:

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z\d]$
```

Which literally means... three digits, followed by a character from either lowercase or uppercase a-z or any digit.